# Heat of Combustion of Carbon Dioxide

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, combustion

I am searching for the low heating value (L.H.V.) heat of combustion of carbon dioxide. I have so far not been able to find any reputable value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you mean the enthalpy of combustion, carbon dioxide doesn't combust. That is it does not react with oxygen to produce water and carbon dioxide. Therefore it has no enthalpy of combustion.

Did you mean carbon **monoxide**?

Comment: I meant carbon dioxide. If gas is being burned in a flare composed of hydrogen, carbon monoxide, and carbon dioxide, would the heat generated by burning the gas only depend on the mass flow of the carbon monoxide and hydrogen? eg. Can I assume the heat of combustion of carbon dioxide is zero?

Comment: @kilojoules: yes